# OS X: How to lock down these frivolous protocols!

Tags: macos, network, firewall, services

I ran a port scan on my Mac (OS X 10.9.4 if its relevant) and i realised all these random protocols with next to no explanation on the internet.

2 of the most unusual protocols include `ndl-aas` and `dec_dlm`, And i recall that keeping track of these open ports on your computer is generally a good idea to maintain your computers security.

So my question

- What are the purposes of the protocols `ndl-aas` and `dec_dlm`?
- And how do I block access to these ports?

Comment: Do you run the server version of Mavericks or did you set up some services with e.g homebrew?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find more details about these services in [SpeedGuide's Port Database](http://www.speedguide.net/ports.php) or the [IANA Service Port Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml):

- [ndl-aas/3128](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=3128#)
- [dec_dlm/625](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=625)

AFAIK neither port is used by OS X out of the box, so you probably have installed some additional stuff on your own (3128 is also used by `squid` for instance).

To check for processes actively listening on these ports, you can use `lsof -i :3128` and `lsof -i :625`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of all ports used by Apple products: [TCP and UDP ports used by Apple software products - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944)

The service names (e.g. dec_dlm) don't reflect necessarily the actual service running on a port. Additionally a service running on your Mac may be diverted to another non-standard port.

According to the above Apple list port 625 is dedicated to:

> **Service or Protocol Name:** Open Directory Proxy (ODProxy) (Unregistered Use)
>   **Service Name:** dec_dlm
>   **RFC:** -
>   **Used by / Additional information:** Open Directory, Server app, Workgroup Manager
>   DirectoryServices in OS X Lion and earlier. Note: This port is registered to DEC DLM

Port 3128 doesn't appear in the Apple list. 
According to [speedguide.net](http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=3128) the following services use port 3128:

> **Service:**                        **Details:**
>   ndl-aas                          Active API Server Port (official assignment)
>   squid-http                     Proxy Server (un-official)
>   squid-http                     squid-http (un-official)
>   http                               Tatsoft (un-official)
>   ReverseWWWTunnel    Reverse WWW Tunnel Backdoor (trojan)
>   RingZero                       RingZero (trojan)
>   Masters Paradise          Masters Paradise (backdoor) (often also listed with port 3129)

Since the last three are Windows malware they are ruled out. Tatsoft (http) is Windows only software. Active API Server Port is completely unknown (to me).

Probably you are running a squid-proxy on your Mac.

To detect the process actively listening on a port use:

```
lsof -i :[port-number]
```

or if no result is presented:

```
sudo lsof -i :[port-number]
```

---

**Portscans**

Scanning the hosts with nmap I found the following ports open on Client/Server 10.9/10.10 (no services like ssh or http running):

**Scanning 127.0.0.1:**

10.9.5 Client/10.10.5 Client:

- 631/tcp open  ipp

10.9.5 Server:

- 311/tcp  open  asip-webadmin
- 631/tcp  open  ipp
- 4443/tcp  open  pharos
- 4444/tcp  open  krb524
- 62308/tcp  open  unknown

10.10.5 Server:

- 88/tcp  open  kerberos-sec
- 631/tcp  open  ipp
- 4443/tcp  open  pharos
- 4444/tcp  open  krb524
- 62308/tcp  open  unknown

**Scanning [ip-address]:**

10.9.5 Client/10.10.5 Client/10.9.5 Server:

- no open ports

10.10.5 Server:

- 88/tcp  open  kerberos-sec

---

Result: the ports 625/3128 are probably used by some third party software. To disable them check the inducing processes with lsof and stop them or unload the respective launch daemon or agents. To block access use a firewall.